# How to link action's response with slot in rasa core?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to build a chat bot with two slots : location and cuisine. 
Here I am facing two problems :

Problem 1 : Sometimes bot is not able to put the response to utter_ask_location(which is action) to the location slot. for example: I gave input ‘delhi’ in the response, but still location slot is shown as none.

Problem 2: Sometimes bot replaces value of a previously updated slot. For example : bot kept ‘kolkata’ in location slot and when I put the response for utter_ask_cuisine, instead of updating to cuisine slot, it updated to location slot.

so can anyone suggest any pointers for the same.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your stories? It actually seems more like an NLU problem than a Rasa Core problem. Seems like NLU does not pick up your entities correctly. Maybe it is worth to try out lookup tables http://blog.rasa.com/improving-entity-extraction/ or to provide more NLU data.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, it was actually NLU problem, once I fed lots of relevant data and stories, bot started working fine.

Comment: I reposted my comment as answer so that you can mark the question as anwered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems more like an NLU problem than a Rasa Core problem since NLU does not pick up your entities correctly. Maybe it is worth to try out lookup tables blog.rasa.com/improving-entity-extraction or to provide more NLU data.